# Make "git gui" break long lines in diffs?

Tags: git, diff

It it possible to make git emit diffs with long lines being wrapped for use in `git gui`?

For command-line use, one  can just change the setting `core.pager`, but this won't affect `git gui`.

Though I have found a working solution and post this question in Q&A style, I hope for solutions that fix any of the following downsides:

**(a)** The filter is applied outside `git gui` too, where it may be unnecessary.

**(b)** The `fold` tool doesn't **indent** wrapped lines, costing readability. I am thinking of something like Emacs' `adaptive-wrap-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using the "textconv" feature, using the `fold` tool as a filter.

It has to be set up in a two-step process.

### Define a driver

This can be done for the repository by running

```
git config diff.DRIVER.textconv 'fold -s'
```

or by editing `.git/config` to contain

```
[diff "DRIVER"]
    textconv = fold -s
```

or globally by

```
git config --global diff.DRIVER.textconv 'fold -s'
```

The tool `fold` can be replaced by more intelligent language-aware filters, as needed. The option `-s` makes fold break at whitespace characters.

On Windows, the fold utility may use DOS line endings, which can conflict with your settings for the repository, leading to spurious `^M` characters in the diff. This can be fixed by using instead

```
sh -c 'fold "$0" | dos2unix'
```

The `sh` wrapper is required, because the textconv protocol expects the specified command to accept a single file name as argument, and produce its output on STDOUT.

### Configuring .gitattributes

Set up the `.gitattributes` file to contain

```
PATTERN diff=DRIVER
```

Here `DRIVER` is an arbitrary driver name and `PATTERN` a wildcard pattern matching the files to which it should be applied, e.g. `*` for "all files" or `*.EXT` for files with the extension `.EXT`.

### Example

For example, in order to run *.tex files through the "fold" filter with "dos2unix":

```
=== .gitattributes ===
*.tex diff=tex

=== .git/config ===
[diff "tex"]
    textconv = sh -c 'fold "$0" | dos2unix'
```